# Translation per IP location

Tags: plugin-development, translation, wp-redirect

I have been wondering if anyone knows how to put wordpress into mode that when a client opens a landing page it automatically redirects him on his native language, possibly defined by his IP address. For example: Person ***A*** is visiting a website which is set by default on English language, since his IP address is from France, it redirects him to www.example.com/fr/ . 
I hope it makes some sense?